# C# Selenium - CSS Selectors - Locating a Sibling

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have searched far and wide on this one... I've come very close to what I'm looking for but I just can't make it work.

I have a table with drop down menus, I would like to read from an adjacent cell and then pick an option based on that cell's value. However, I only want to do this to td classes with the name "Color Mismatch". See the Snippet Below:

```html
<td class="Color-Mismatch">
                    <span style="display: none">Blue</span>
                    <select class="input-small" id="select_color" name="select_color"><option value=""></option>
<option value="2">Red</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Blue</option>

</select>
                </td>

<td class="Color-Mismatch">
                 Red <- I want to read this value and then choose it from the dropdown
<br>
  
  <td class="Color-Match">
                    <span style="display: none">Blue</span>
                    <select class="input-small" id="select_color" name="select_color"><option value=""></option>
<option value="2">Red</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Blue</option>

</select>
                </td>

<td class="Color-Match">
                 Blue <- I want to ignore this one because the colors already match
```

The first `"td class="Color-Mismatch"` contains the drop down menu while the second `"td class="Color-Mismatch"` contains the value it should be. When the page loads it will compare the values, and if they do not match will name them accordingly.

I can easily find and cycle through all `"Color-Mismatch"` classes and choose a dropdown option. However I can't quite figure out how to pull the value from the other `"Color-Mismatch"` class and then select the same value from the dropdown. Long story short -> I want to cycle through all `"Color-Mismatch"` classes and make the colors match by choosing the correct drop down value. Red -> Red   Blue -> Blue etc.

I would like to continue using CSS selectors to accomplish this. I am loading all `Color-Mismatch` classes' drop down boxes into a list like so: `IList<IWebElement> testList = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td.Color-Mismatch select"));`. Then I am running through a `foreach` loop

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about an XPath based approach? Thanks.

Comment: I would prefer to stick with CSS Selectors, but would consider XPath solutions as well.

Answer (score -1):

If the structure of your HTML remains the same as above, the below solution works perfectly fine...

```
List<WebElement> objDropDowns = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.Color-Mismatch:first-child select"));
List<WebElement> objMatching = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.Color-Mismatch:last-child"));

    if(objDropDowns.size() > 0){

        for(int iCount=0; iCount<objDropDowns.size(); iCount++){
            String selectedText = objDropDowns.get(iCount).getText();
            String expectedText = objMatching.get(iCount).getText();
            if (!selectedText.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedText)){
                Select objSelect = new Select(objDropDowns.get(iCount));
                objSelect.selectByVisibleText(expectedText);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am a Java guy, I just noticed you posted as a C# query !! :)

Comment: Incase you want to go by the sibling approach, you can replace `td.Color-Mismatch:last-child` with `td.Color-Mismatch+td.Color-Mismatch`. Notice the `+` symbol that indicates next sibling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will give it a try and let you know the results!

Comment: In a way, yes. But I ended up doing it another way. I looked at elements position on the page and then compared its position on the y axis to see if they matched.